# Using Vb.NET and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

net and wondering if I could get some get help with this problem. The problem im having is i create an array in vb.net onload and trying to use that array in javascript. Is there anyway I can do do this? An example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you any code you can post? It's a bit like stabbing in the dark otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Daok.
Lets assume you want to create an html file with some html and script within.

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\myfile.html"
Dim js As String

js="<script language=javascript>" & _
"my_array=" & my_vb_array & ";" & _
"</script>"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
objWriter.Write(js)
objWriter.Close()
MsgBox("Text written to file")
Else
MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print from VB.NET a string with the javascript tag and inside using `Var myVariableJsSide1 = ...` and then later in the client side use this variable.